# Добавление плавности для открытия tab-а Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Нужно добавить плавность для открытия `tab`-а. Есть блок, при клике на `li` класса "`advantages-col`" появляется нижний `div` блок класса "`panel`". Но появляется резко, мне нужно добавить плавность. Через jQuery пробовала с помощью `fadeIn` и `fadeToggle`, к сожалению работает некорректно, то есть плавность работает но открывает одновременно все либо несколько вкладок. А также пробовала в класс `active` добавить `transition` и стили добавляла в блок с javascript-ом. К сожалению тоже безрезультативно. Прошу помочь. Благодарю заранее за ответ.

```js
var tabPanels = document.querySelectorAll(".panel");
var tabButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".advantages-col");

function showPanel(panelIndex) {
  tabButtons.forEach(function(node) {
    node.classList.remove("active");
  });
  tabButtons[panelIndex].classList.add("active");
  tabPanels.forEach(function(node) {
    node.style.display = "none";
  });
  tabPanels[panelIndex].style.display = "flex";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-target="#protect" onclick="showPanel(6)" class="advantages-col active">
    <div class="flex part_one_adv">
      <div data-target="#protect">Защита от проникновения</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <div class="panel active" id="protect">
    <div class="flex panel_col">
      <div class="pl-16">
        <h4>Защита от проникновения</h4>
        <p>Защита от проникновенияЗащита от проникновенияЗащита от проникновенияЗащита от проникновенияЗащита от проникновенияЗащита от проникновенияЗащита от проникновенияЗащита от проникновенияЗащита от проникновенияЗащита от проникновения</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mob_menu_btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-red-light call-modal-show">Оставить заявку</button></div>
  </div>
  <li data-target="#protect2" onclick="showPanel(7)" class="advantages-col">
    <div class="flex part_one_adv">
      <div data-target="#protect2">Защита от проникновения</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <div class="panel" id="protect2">
    <div class="flex panel_col">
      <div class="pl-16">
        <h4>Защита от проникновения</h4>
        <p>Защита от проникновенияЗащита от проникновенияЗащита от проникновенияЗащита от проникновенияЗащита от проникновенияЗащита от проникновенияЗащита от проникновенияЗащита от проникновенияЗащита от проникновенияЗащита от проникновения</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mob_menu_btn"><button type="button" class="btn">Оставить заявку</button></div>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вам надо сделать появление блоков только на двух li, то можно обойтись и без js.

```html
    <label for="input">press me!!</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="input">
    <div class="test2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum id non velit eos ea nesciunt dolores, recusandae, nulla vero consequatur inventore repellendus? Quas eveniet harum, voluptates minima iusto voluptas illum.
    </div>
    <style>
        label{
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 2px;
        }
        input[type="checkbox"]{
            display: none;
        }
        .test2{
            opacity: 0;
            transition: 2s;
        }
        input:checked ~ .test2{
            opacity: 1;
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
```